# how to Decode QR code from Photo library

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, zbar-sdk

I'm using ZbarQR code reader in iOS SDK. I want to scan a photo which has Qrcode in it from photo library of a device( not in simulator ). Is it possible to do this? if yes, How?

Please help me

Comment: have tried anything???

Comment: i have tried , it is working fine,  and it is working only for from out side QR code Image, but  i want ,select the photo from device photo library  , and its read (decode) automatically, if you have related idea , please share me